# Gnome Calendar and Contacts have generic Gnome application icons in the launcher

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, calendar

I just did a "minimal" install of Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 and everything's working well for the most part.

However, after installing Gnome Calendar and Contacts, they only have generic Gnome application icons (looks like a purple diamond with a gear inside).  Other apps I have installed, such as Evolution, correctly display their icons.

I assume I'm missing a set of icons or perhaps some part of a theme, but I'm not very familiar with how this works, so I'm not clear on what I need to install.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I screwed up my system so bad trying to fix this that it no longer boots into a graphical environment and I don’t know how to fix that either. But this is the icon that was appearing instead of the icons for Gnome Calendar and Gnome Contacts: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons#/media/File%3AGnome-application-x-executable.svg

Answer (score 0):

The default icon set for Gnome is contained in two packages in synaptic:

- adwaita-icon-theme
- adwaita-icon-theme-full

I did a normal system install and only have adwaita-icon-theme and everything looks normal to me, so try just installing or reinstalling that package.

Comment: Well, I tried installing adwaita-icon-theme-full, and switching my theme to that from whatever the Ubuntu default was, but the Gnome Calendar / Contacts icons were still generic icons. Then I tried reinstalling adwaita-icon-theme and hosed my system so bad, I'll probably need to reinstall. :D I'll try doing a full install of Ubuntu instead of minimal next time and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you actually find the issue with the icons in the end? Are we talking about these icons here? https://twitter.com/audiores/status/1349958006474203136